# Android Google Maps stop unfortunately on other device

Tags: android, google-maps

Why my GoogleMaps is making my app stop unfortunately when I run it in another devices? Here is my code:

```
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void onMapSearch(View view) {
        EditText locationSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
        List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;

        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Click here"));
            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    String frst = address.getLocality();
                    Double lat=address.getLatitude();
                    Double longi=address.getLongitude();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.VERIFICATION, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.CITYNAME, frst);
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.LAT,""+lat);
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.LONG,""+longi);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // create class object
        final GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);
        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
                if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MapsActivity.this))
                    sendGetAddressRequest(latitude, longitude);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "need_network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                        if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
                            if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MapsActivity.this)) {
                                sendGetAddressRequest(latitude, longitude);

                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "need_network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "couldn't get your current location enter manually", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, 10000);
            }

        } else {
        }

    }

    private void sendGetAddressRequest(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // lat.setText("latitude" + latitude);
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MapsActivity.this)) {
            getAddressAsync = new GetAddress(latitude, longitude);
            getAddressAsync.execute();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "need_network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private class GetAddress extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        double latitude, longitude;

        public GetAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = null;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&ka&sensor=false");
            // Log.d(TAG, "CURRENT ADDRESS API : " + "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&ka&sensor=false");
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result = jsonObject.toString();
            //  Log.d(TAG, "Address : " + result);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            progressBar.setClickable(true);
//            currentLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
                    if (result.has("results")) {
                        JSONArray array = result.getJSONArray("results");
                        if (array.length() > 0) {
                            JSONObject place = array.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONArray components = place.getJSONArray("address_components");
                            for (int i = 0; i < components.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject component = components.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONArray types = component.getJSONArray("types");
                                for (int j = 0; j < types.length(); j++) {
                                    if (types.getString(j).equals("locality")) {
                                        cityName = component.getString("long_name");
                                    } else if (types.getString(j).equals("premise")) {
                                        plot = component.getString("long_name");
                                    } else if (types.getString(j).equals("sublocality_level_1")) {
                                        area = component.getString("long_name");
                                    } else if (types.getString(j).equals("administrative_area_level_1")) {
                                        state = component.getString("long_name");
                                    } else if (types.getString(j).equals("postal_code")) {
                                        postalCode = component.getString("long_name");
                                    } else if (types.getString(j).equals("country")) {
                                        country = component.getString("long_name");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            formattedAddress = place.getString("formatted_address");
                            onMapReady(mMap);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Log.d(TAG, "Locality : " + cityName + ", Area : " + area + ", State : " + state + ", PostalCode : " + postalCode + ", Country : " + country);

            }


        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).draggable(true).title("Current Location"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(30));
//        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
//
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("City",cityName);
//                intent.putExtra("Area",area);
//                intent.putExtra("State",state);
//                intent.putExtra("PostalCode",postalCode);
//                intent.putExtra("Country",country);
//                intent.putExtra("Plot",plot);
//                startActivity(intent);
//
//            }
//        });
    }

}
```

When I run my app on other devices, it crashes sometimes but when I run it on my phone, it works fine. On most of devices, I got a crash.

I don't know where it is throwing an exception.
Suggest me something guys, please, I'm stuck in this from a very long time. I want to fix it on every phone.

Comment: can you share the log trace?

Comment: Actually when i shared my apk with others then only it is crashing,,,otherwise when i test it on my device it doent crash

Comment: We need to see the logtrace, otherwise we can't guess the exception raised on other phones.

Comment: May be it is because something google maps api doesnt fetch user's location

Comment: Please share the exception or error details which is printed in your Android Monitor's log trace so that I can help you to get it fixed.

Comment: Please post your error here, there are many possibilities to occuring this like play service version should be wrong, run time persmission issue etc. @neha